# Google Sign-in - getting the callback from AndroidLauncher to libgdx screen

Tags: android, libgdx

Google Play Sign-in in Libgdx : 
Please guide for the following questions.

1. After the sign-in / sign-out, I wish to get the call back from the android launcher to the libgdx screen. I am using the below statement as in the example given by "badlogic"

   ```
   actionResolver.loginGPGS();
   ```
2. Everytime when the user signs in the app has to remember the login and it has to show the info that the user is in signed in status

How do achieve the above 2 requirement ?

Thanks

Comment: I also have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add these to your android project:

[BaseGameUtils for Google Play Services](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils)

There is this method in GameHelper class

```
/** Returns whether or not the user is signed in. */
public boolean isSignedIn() {
    return mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();
}
```

Then you just add this below method to your ActionResolver

```
public boolean getSignedInGPGS();
```

Then to use it inside your AndroidLauncher:

```
@Override
    public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
        return gameHelper.isSignedIn();
    }
```

So it returns whether player is signed in or not.
Just use that boolean value inside your core project to do stuff.

Comment: the sign in happens in the activity .. how to set up the listener from the libgdx screen